# What's the best way of managing user authentication and sessions on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, authentication, session

I usually use JWT tokens but I know this is not so secure because when you store the token on LocalStorage you are susceptible to attacks.

What is the best and most secure way for a good session and auth management?

Comment: "susceptible to attacks" compared to what? And a attacking scenario would be nice to see. There is no 100% security. JWT are completly fine to use. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generally accepted standard is storing JWT inside an `httpOnly` cookie. So the JWT/Cookie will only be sent to the HTTP server and would not be accessible for reading or writing on the client side. To make it more secure you can set `SameSite=strict` to eliminate cross site request forgery (CSRF) unless you require the JWT to fetch information from a different domain.

There probably are more secure ways to do this?, but I believe this would be more than enough for an average website.